# JavaScript - Flatten Array of Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am working with an array of objects and need to flatten and re-assign the data set into an array of single objects using the object values as the new object keys.

Incoming Data:

```
results = [
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Jim' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Fredsburg' },
    ],
  },
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Greg' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Waverly' },
    ],
  },
];
```

Desired Result:

```
output = [
  {
    id: 1, FirstName: 'Jim', LastName: 'Jones', City: 'Fredsburg',
  },
  {
    id: 2, FirstName: 'Greg', LastName: 'Jones', City: 'Waverly',
  },
];
```

My current attempt gets me to placing the updated key/value pairs in the correct order, but creates a huge array of single objects.

Current Code:

```
const results = [];

surveyResults.map(s => s.surveyValues)
  .forEach(s => Object.entries(s)
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
    Object.entries(value)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (k === 'name') {
          results.push({
            id: value.id,
            [v]: value.value.toString(),
          });
        }
    });
}));
```

Current Code Output:

```
[
  {
    id: 135, FirstName: 'Jim',
  },
  {
    id: 136, LastName: 'Jones',
  },
  {
    id: 137, City: 'Fredsburg',
  },
  {
    id: 135, FirstName: 'Greg',
  },
  {
    id: 136, LastName: 'Jones',
  },
  {
    id: 137, City: 'Waverly',
  },
]
```

What am I missing and why is my code not created the new arrays of objects as desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `map` and `reduce` to accomplish this. I'm also accessing an index `i` in the map function's callback to set the id property and `string.replace()` to strip the space from the `FirstName` and `LastName` keys.

```js
const results = [
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Jim' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Fredsburg' },
    ],
  },
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Greg' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Waverly' },
    ],
  },
];


const result = results.map((e, i) => 
  e.surveyValues.reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.name.replace(" ", "")] = e.value;
    return a;
  }, {id: i + 1})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create each object in the outer `map()` loop, and add properties to it in the inner `forEach()`.

```js
surveyResults = [
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Jim' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Fredsburg' },
    ],
  },
  {
    surveyValues: [
      { id: 135, name: 'First Name', value: 'Greg' },
      { id: 136, name: 'Last Name', value: 'Jones' },
      { id: 137, name: 'City', value: 'Waverly' },
    ],
  },
];

const results = surveyResults.map((s, i) => {
  let v = s.surveyValues;
  let obj = {id: i};
  v.forEach(item => obj[item.name.replace(/\s+/g, "")] = item.value.toString());
  return obj;
});

console.log(results);
```